# dateRangeInput returns NA

Tags: r, date, shiny

With `shiny 1.5.0`, I have trouble using `dateRangeInput`.

When parameters `end` and `max` are equal, the end date returns `NA`. And if I set `start` to `min`, the `textOutput` does not even appear!

Note: I get the correct value if I don't set the format, or if I use an older version of shiny

Any ideas?

Repex:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textOutput("dateprint"),
    dateRangeInput("daterange",
                   label = "Dates:",
                   start = Sys.Date() - 6, end = Sys.Date(),
                   min = Sys.Date() - 7, max = Sys.Date(),
                   format = "dd/mm/yy"
                   )),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$dateprint <- renderText({
      c(as.character(input$daterange[1]), as.character(input$daterange[2]))
    })
  }          
)
```

Comment: Commenting out the format line makes it run fine...

Comment: I think the formatting has to match between what you supply for start, end, min, max and the format that you specify. `format(Sys.Date())` returns yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It looks like a bug because you can select manually max and it will accept your input and remove the `NA`. I think you could submit this to https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues.